# VBS script to emulate a HTML form

Tags: php, vbscript

I am looking to create a VBS script that can post three parameters as well as upload a file.  I have a PHP file sitting on the server which is working perfectly using a form to send the parameters and file, but I want to create a script that means I don't require the form at all and could POST directly from a script.

I am really struggling to find any good / working examples... I wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction?

This is my PHP file

---

```php
<?php

   $parameter1 = $_GET['parameter1'];
   $parameter2 = $_GET['parameter2'];
   $parameter3 = $_GET['parameter3'];

   $tempname = $dataname."--". date("Y_m_d--H_i_s--"). "file.txt";
   $filename = '/myfiles/'. $tempname;

   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filechoice']['tmp_name'], $filename)) {      
      echo "uploaded succesfully"; 
   } else {
        echo "error uploading"; 
   } 
?>
```

---

This is the VBScript I have put together via a few sources so far....

---

```vb
Dim strURL
Dim HTTP
Dim dataFile
Dim dataRequest
Dim objStream
strURL = "http://localhost/uploadfile.php?parameter1=mytest1&parameter2=hello&parameter3=thankyou"


Set HTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 2
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile "c:\1234.txt"
dataFile = objStream.ReadText

dataRequest = "filechoice=" & dataFile

HTTP.open "POST", strURL, False
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
HTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(dataRequest)

WScript.Echo "Now uploading file"

HTTP.send dataRequest
WScript.Echo HTTP.responseText

Set HTTP = Nothing
```

---

I have used print_r($_GET) on the PHP file and can see the parameters are being sent perfectly....

But if I try and look for a file i.e print_r($_FILES) - it shows nothing and nothing is uploaded..

Comment: Can you post what you have in the PHP file?

Comment: You can do this using the [`IServerXMLHTTPRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754586(v=vs.85).aspx) object, the same way you would make any AJAX request.